# Unable to code sign with Windows signtool

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, code-signing

I'm trying to understand code signing of executable files on Windows by creating my own self-signed certificate and successfully signing a file. The signtool is throwing an error and saying that "No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I've done:

Following some instructions from MS and other blogs, I create a self signed certificate like so:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation Cert:\LocalMachine\my -dnsname cameronnokes.com

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -Force -AsPlainText

Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\LocalMachine\my\C7A94086D80A42151551A9FCCEACBC0B4A9ABA1A -FilePath 'C:\Users\Cameron Nokes\selfcert.pfx' -Password $pwd

Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\my
```

That last Get-ChildItem command displays the thumbprint and subject and looks like I'd expect it to.

Now, in cmd, I run:

```
signtool.exe sign /f selfcert.pfx /p password /debug test.ps1


The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: cameronnokes.com
    Issued by: cameronnokes.com
    Expires:   Sat Aug 05 12:37:28 2017
    SHA1 hash: C7A94086D80A42151551A9FCCEACBC0B4A9ABA1A

After EKU filter, 0 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 0 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Comment: You must generate a certificate with an Code Signing enhanced key usage. You're not and that's why it says none left after EKU filter. New-SelfSignedCertificate does not allow you to specify the EKUs so you cannot use it for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a moment to remember the quirks of certreq, it's there by default and you can use it to generate a key for you.

Make this request.inf:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=cameronnokes.com"
Exportable = TRUE
KeyLength = 2048
KeySpec = 1
KeyUsage = 0xA0
RequestType = Cert

[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 ; Code signing
```

Then run this command:

```
certreq -new request.inf nothing.csr
```

You can then delete both request.inf and nothing.csr. At this point you have a self-signed code-signing certificate in your personal store.

```
$Certificate = Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My |
    Where-Object { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq 'Code Signing' -and $_.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date) } |
    Sort-Object NotAfter |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

You wouldn't really want to be so vague when choosing the certificate, it's like this for the example only.

Finally, sign a ps1:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature test.ps1 -Certificate $Certificate
```

Simple, right?

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I was looking for a way to specifically sign with the signtool. After creating the certificate, I was able to sign successfully by passing the SHA1 to the signtool. Totally simple. Ha.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need - except when I run `certreq`, it prompts me to select a smart card device, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Ah - adding `ProviderName="Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"` to the `[NewRequest]` section fixed that for me, having found https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e777c074-9b6a-47bb-a8ce-005b92168aea/insert-smart-card-popup-when-creating-a-cert-request-using-certreqexe?forum=winserversecurity